# How to run tensorflow optimization with different initial conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am relatively new to tensorflow. Is it possible to set up a tensorflow optimization and run the optimization with different initial conditions, without re-running the set-up code?

For example, consider the following psuedo code:

```
def foo(N):
    # do some tensor math
    return A

N = tf.get_variable("N", initializer = N_init)
A = foo(N)

cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(A, target)
optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
optimizer.minimize(sess)
```

My function foo takes a long time to run, and I get different results depending on the initial condition. I would like to set up the problem, and then run the optimization with different initializations for my variable N without re-running the function foo more than once. Can I do this? How?

Comment: Cannot you serialize the outcome of the foo function?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that? My foo function is a whole bunch of matrix algebra (matrix multiplications, inverses, etc.).

Comment: But are those deterministic or not? If they are deterministic then you may do precomputations, right?